# SwiftData how to form a search predicate with a one to many model

Tags: predicate, swift-data

I am working in Xcode 15 (beta) migrating to SwiftData and am having a hard time figuring out how to form a predicate in my one to many model.  The desired result is to return a query that returns only the articles and sections where the article "search" field contains the string a user is searching for.

here is my current model:

```
@Model
class SectionsSD {    
  @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
  var section: String
  var rank: String  
  var toArticles: [ArticlesSD]?
    
  init(id:String, section: String, rank: String) {
      self.id = id
      self.section = section
      self.rank = rank
  }
}
@Model
class ArticlesSD {
  var id: String
  var title: String
  var summary: String
  var search: String
  var section: String
  var body: String
  @Relationship(inverse: \SectionsSD.toArticles) var toSection: SectionsSD?
 
  init(id: String, title: String, summary: String, search: String, section: String, body: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.summary = summary
    self.search = search
    self.section = section
    self.body = body
  }
}
```

In CoreData I was able to do the following in my code to pass the search predicate (filter being the user input search text):

```
  _fetchRequest = FetchRequest<SectionsEntity>(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.rank)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "toArticles.search CONTAINS %@", filter))
```

How do I get to that "toArticles.search"?  Clearly with the new model/structure/relationships in SwiftData I can't figure out how to form the predicate to achieve the same result as before.  Below is what I tried but Xcode doesn't like it.

```
  let searchPredicate = #Predicate<SectionsSD> { $0.toArticles?.contains(filter) }
  _fetchRequest = Query(filter: searchPredicate)
```

Any suggestions and examples on how to form this predicate would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a nested query

```
 let predicate = #Predicate< SectionsSD > {
    $0.toArticles?.contains {
        $0.search.contains(filter)
    }
}
```